# Install with Gem on macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, macos-catalina, travis-rb

I was trying to install [Travis.rb](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb) as documented by the team. However, the location that `gem` tried to install to is protected by the OS. So I got an error like this:

```
% gem install travis
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I tried the following command but did not fully work - installation was okay, but I could not call `% travis`.

```
gem install travis --user-install
```

---

Configuration: I am using `gem` shipped with the OS:

```
% ruby -v  
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

Comment: Your user may not have proper permissions... Did you try `sudo` ?

Comment: @RichardBarber I purposefully did not use `sudo`, because what I am installing should not have root access when executing.

Comment: Installing with `sudo` doesn’t give the executable root permissions.  Calling the executable with `sudo` does that.  Installing with `sudo` gives the installer permission to install it in whatever dir for which you don’t have proper permissions set.  `sudo` your install or repair permissions.

Comment: @RichardBarber thanks for clarification on that. Another thing is that, I believe `/Library/` is now a protected directory by the OS. I don't feel `travis` should go so far that I need to disable SIP to install.

Comment: Yes it is protected. I usually install stuff to the /usr/local or /opt/local areas.

Comment: yes, so I guess what I can do is to install to user location, but unfortunately `--user-install` does not work.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Answer (score 3):

It is always a good idea to do user installation and avoid system things. Therefore doing...

```
gem install travis --user-install
```

... seems to be recommended way.

After that, the executable files are there, but you have to fix you PATH to run by adding your ~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0 folder to the path. See https://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue from the question seems similar to what I faced. The solution that worked for me is coming from the [installation instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/) for Jekyll.

There are few important points:

- macOS comes preinstalled with Ruby, but they don’t recommend using that version to install Jekyll
- they recommend `chruby` as a Ruby version manager because it’s the simplest and least likely to cause issues

So the 3 steps to get a working Ruby environment are:

Install `chruby` and `ruby-install` with Homebrew:

```
brew install chruby ruby-install xz
```

Install latest version of Ruby:

```
ruby-install ruby
```

Configure shell:

```
echo "source $(brew --prefix)/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "source $(brew --prefix)/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "chruby ruby-3.1.2" >> ~/.zshrc # run 'chruby' to see actual version
```

(for Bash use .bash_profile instead of .zshrc in the last command)

You can check the version of your installed Ruby with `ruby -v`.